# Determine and list the top 5 for a given group

Tags: r, list, dplyr, group-by

I need to determine the top 5 defects (determined by distinct count of event_id) for each company and list them as shown in df_answer.

```
df= data.frame(company=c("X","X","X",
                         "X","X","X",
                         "X","X","X",
                         "Y","Y","Y",
                         "Y","Y","Y"),
               event_id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15),
               defect=c("code1","code1","code1",
                        "code1","code3","code3",
                        "code4","code3","code2",
                        "code2","code5","code2",
                        "code6","code2","code5"))


df_answer=data.frame(company=c("X","Y"),
                     max_defect_list=c("code1;code3;code2;code4",
                                       "code2;code5;code6"),
                     max=c("4;3;1,1","3;2;1"))
```

This is what I have tried:

```
df%>%
  group_by(company)%>%
  add_count(defect)%>%
  summarise(
    num_reports=n_distinct(event_id),
    max_defect_list = paste(unique(defect[which(n %in% slice_max(n,5))]), collapse = ';'),
    max=slice_max(n,5)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach using `dplyr` commands -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  count(company, defect) %>%
  slice_max(n, n = 5, by = company) %>%
  summarise(across(c(defect, n), ~paste0(.x, collapse = ";")), .by = company)

#  company                  defect       n
#1       X code1;code3;code2;code4 4;3;1;1
#2       Y       code2;code5;code6   3;2;1
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution! I was wondering if there was anyway there could just be a group_by( company) because I want to summarize other details about the company in the summarize function

Comment: @Ashti I am using the newer syntax of `.by` to group it by `company`. However, if you wish to use `group_by(company)` sure you can use it by adding it after `slice_max`.

Answer (score 2):

You won't return the top five as there are not five defects per group in your sample data. I've created a new sample dataset to for illustrative purposes, but this method will work on your original sample data as well:

```
library(dplyr)

# Sample data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(company = rep(c("X", "y"), each = 40),
                 event_id = 1:80,
                 defect = sample(paste0("code", 1:5), 80, replace = TRUE))
df %>%
  group_by(company) %>%
  add_count(defect) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-event_id) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(company) %>%
  slice_max(n, n = 5)

# A tibble: 10 × 3
# Groups:   company [2]
company   defect      n
<chr>      <chr>    <int>
1  X       code1     11
2  X       code2     10
3  X       code4      8
4  X       code5      7
5  X       code3      4
6  y       code3      9
7  y       code2      8
8  y       code5      8
9  y       code1      8
10 y       code4      7
```

And the result from your original data:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 3
# Groups:   company [2]
  company defect     n
  <chr>   <chr>  <int>
1 X       code1      4
2 X       code3      3
3 X       code4      1
4 X       code2      1
5 Y       code2      3
6 Y       code5      2
7 Y       code6      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way by piping `dplyr`

```
df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(company,defect) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(count = n()) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup(.) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(company) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(desc(count)) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(max_defect_list = paste(defect, collapse = ";"),
                   max = paste(count, collapse = ";")) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup(.)

 `summarise()` has grouped output by 'company'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  company max_defect_list         max    
  <chr>   <chr>                   <chr>  
1 X       code1;code3;code2;code4 4;3;1;1
2 Y       code2;code5;code6       3;2;1
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

df <- setDT(df)
df[,by = c("company","defect"), .(count = .N)][, by = "company", .(max_defect_list = paste(defect, collapse = ";"),
                                                                   max = paste(count, collapse = ";"))]
```